# Can I upload to another bucket in my Firebase-project with fileRef.put()?

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage

The page https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files tells nearly everything about uploading files to Firebase storage from a web client. Except that it has no information about buckets. The examples all uses the default bucket.

If I have another bucket in my Firebase-project, can I upload to that somehow?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can do that. There is a bucket import mechanism in the Firebase Storage console hidden behind the three-dots overflow menu. I believe you can then reference it by initializing a new Firebase App instance using [initializeApp](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase#initializeapp), providing the name of that bucket in the options.

Comment: Thanks, yes I noticed that but I am not sure of how to actually use it in this case. I am using the default initialization (`init.js`). What should I do after this?

Comment: You will need to use an additional app instance using the API I linked to.  Give it a try, and if it doesn't work, post another question with the code that isn't working the way you expect.

Comment: Thank you! The option to import a bucket was hidden and found it thanks to your tip!!